# Attempting to replace https domain in Nginx

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm running Nginx on Ubuntu 20.04 and attempting to create an NGINX configuration to change the domain of specific http request to a different one. If any https request on the host is made to the domain login.windows.net I want to swap the domain to use login.microsoftonline.com.

In example, if a request looks like this:

https://login.windows.net/fe3f3811-3e28-4a4e-a122-3e1135c01bf2/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

and I'd like to rewrite it as:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/fe3f3811-3e28-4a4e-a122-3e1135c01bf2/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

My Nginx config looks like this:

```
events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}

http {

  ##
  # Basic Settings
  ##

  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  # server_tokens off;

  # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
  # server_name_in_redirect off;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ##
  # SSL Settings
  ##

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  ##
  # Logging Settings
  ##

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  ##
  # Gzip Settings
  ##

  gzip on;

  # gzip_vary on;
  # gzip_proxied any;
  # gzip_comp_level 6;
  # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
  # gzip_http_version 1.1;
  # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

  ##
  # Virtual Host Configs
  ##
  server {
    # The listen directive serves content based on the port defined
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    ssl on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    location /fe3f3811-3e28-4a4e-a122-3e1135c01bf2 {
        rewrite ^/fe3f3811-3e28-4a4e-a122-3e1135c01bf2(.*)$ https://login.microsoftonline.com/$1 redirect;
    }
  }
  

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
 
}
```

However; whenever I load and restart nginx with this configuration and make a curl request:

curl -L https://login.windows.net/fe3f3811-3e28-4a4e-a122-3e1135c01bf2/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

It does not replace the configuration.

I've also tried to do a proxy pass configuration:

```
location /fe3f3811-3e28-4a4e-a122-3e1135c01bf/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration {
                  proxy_pass_request_headers on;
                  proxy_pass https://login.microsoftonline.com/fe3f3811-3e28-4a4e-a122-3e1135c01bf/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration;
    }
```

Still does not work. How do I do a simple replace of the domain for an https call??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add a server block especially for your domain with the following config:

```
server {
    # add served servername
    server_name login.windows.net;
    
    # your stuff for ssl
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    ssl on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/reverse-error.log;

    # return redirect to other domain
    return 301 https://login.microsoftonline.com$request_uri;
}
```